# How can I get the template context from the template loader in Django?

Tags: django-templates, django-context

I need to load some templates which path depends of their context. I created a custom [Loader](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#using-an-alternative-template-language). How can I access to the context of the template from my custom template loader?

Answer (score 0):

Could you give an example of what kind of project structure you have?

Is it:

```
    myproject/
        myapps1/templates/myapp_template
```

or is it the regular:

```
    myproject/
        myapps1
        templates/myapps1/myapp_template
```

The reason for asking is that a lot of issues can be solved through template tags, `url.py` and the project structure.

In the first type, you might need custom loaders. In the second, template tags and the `myapps1/urls.py`would do the trick.

Comment: I have come to the conclusion that there is no way of obtaining the context from a template loader, so finally I overwrote the rendering function of the `TemplateView` and developed a custom `include` template tag :) ty!

Comment: Excellent. I'll use that in the future some where.